# Filter_at selected columns with multiple str_detect patterns

Tags: r, regex, filter, dplyr

What i should do should be pretty easy, yet, the newcomer that I am, I spent way too much time on trying to achieve this. With this script I try to filter out ALL observations from a data frame that contain ANY of the mentioned patterns.

The script is:

```
df1 <- filter_at(df, vars(contains("Pair")), 
                 any_vars(str_detect(., pattern="quinoaquinoa|lupinelupine", negate=TRUE)))
```

I do not get any error when I run this, however nothing changes and the expressions are not taken out from the dataframe. As i understand these functions  i could also place a `!` in front of `str_detect` instead of the `negate=TRUE`, however neither works.

Note, the data frame is actually larger (has columns other than those containing "Pair", and the patterns to filter out will always be different and are retrieved from another data frame.

The data frame looks like:

```
str(df)

'data.frame':   653 obs. of  6 variables:
 $ Pair_1: Factor w/ 7 levels "grasscloverleycamelina",..: 3 7 7 3 3 3 7 6 6 6 ...
 $ Pair_2: Factor w/ 20 levels "camelinacamelina",..: 10 6 6 8 8 10 6 8 8 10 ...
 $ Pair_3: Factor w/ 20 levels "camelinacamelina",..: 19 20 20 20 19 19 20 20 20 16 ...
 $ Pair_4: Factor w/ 23 levels "camelinacamelina",..: 9 8 8 8 9 9 4 1 1 5 ...
 $ Pair_5: Factor w/ 20 levels "camelinacamelina",..: 9 12 16 16 13 13 12 12 11 11 ...
 $ Pair_6: Factor w/ 20 levels "camelinacamelina",..: 20 13 9 17 20 20 5 7 8 8 ...
```

`dput` dataframe:

```
structure(list(Pair_1 = structure(c(3L, 7L, 7L, 3L, 3L, 3L), .Label = c("grasscloverleycamelina", 
"grasscloverleyquinoa", "lupinecamelina", "lupinegrasscloverley", 
"lupinelupine", "lupinequinoa", "lupinespringcereal"), class = "factor"), 
    Pair_2 = structure(c(10L, 6L, 6L, 8L, 8L, 10L), .Label = c("camelinacamelina", 
    "camelinagrasscloverley", "camelinalupine", "camelinaquinoa", 
    "camelinaspringcereal", "grasscloverleycamelina", "grasscloverleygrasscloverley", 
    "grasscloverleylupine", "grasscloverleyquinoa", "grasscloverleyspringcereal", 
    "quinoacamelina", "quinoagrasscloverley", "quinoalupine", 
    "quinoaquinoa", "quinoaspringcereal", "springcerealcamelina", 
    "springcerealgrasscloverley", "springcereallupine", "springcerealquinoa", 
    "springcerealspringcereal"), class = "factor"), Pair_3 = structure(c(19L, 
    20L, 20L, 20L, 19L, 19L), .Label = c("camelinacamelina", 
    "camelinagrasscloverley", "camelinalupine", "camelinaquinoa", 
    "camelinaspringcereal", "grasscloverleycamelina", "grasscloverleygrasscloverley", 
    "grasscloverleylupine", "grasscloverleyquinoa", "grasscloverleyspringcereal", 
    "quinoacamelina", "quinoagrasscloverley", "quinoalupine", 
    "quinoaquinoa", "quinoaspringcereal", "springcerealcamelina", 
    "springcerealgrasscloverley", "springcereallupine", "springcerealquinoa", 
    "springcerealspringcereal"), class = "factor"), Pair_4 = structure(c(9L, 
    8L, 8L, 8L, 9L, 9L), .Label = c("camelinacamelina", "camelinagrasscloverley", 
    "camelinalupine", "camelinaquinoa", "camelinaspringcereal", 
    "grasscloverleycamelina", "grasscloverleygrasscloverley", 
    "grasscloverleyquinoa", "grasscloverleyspringcereal", "lupinecamelina", 
    "lupinegrasscloverley", "lupinelupine", "lupinequinoa", "lupinespringcereal", 
    "quinoacamelina", "quinoagrasscloverley", "quinoaquinoa", 
    "quinoaspringcereal", "springcerealcamelina", "springcerealgrasscloverley", 
    "springcereallupine", "springcerealquinoa", "springcerealspringcereal"
    ), class = "factor"), Pair_5 = structure(c(9L, 12L, 16L, 
    16L, 13L, 13L), .Label = c("camelinacamelina", "camelinagrasscloverley", 
    "camelinaquinoa", "camelinaspringcereal", "grasscloverleycamelina", 
    "grasscloverleygrasscloverley", "grasscloverleyquinoa", "grasscloverleyspringcereal", 
    "lupinecamelina", "lupinegrasscloverley", "lupinequinoa", 
    "lupinespringcereal", "quinoacamelina", "quinoagrasscloverley", 
    "quinoaquinoa", "quinoaspringcereal", "springcerealcamelina", 
    "springcerealgrasscloverley", "springcerealquinoa", "springcerealspringcereal"
    ), class = "factor"), Pair_6 = structure(c(20L, 13L, 9L, 
    17L, 20L, 20L), .Label = c("camelinacamelina", "camelinagrasscloverley", 
    "camelinaquinoa", "camelinaspringcereal", "grasscloverleycamelina", 
    "grasscloverleygrasscloverley", "grasscloverleyquinoa", "grasscloverleyspringcereal", 
    "lupinecamelina", "lupinegrasscloverley", "lupinequinoa", 
    "lupinespringcereal", "quinoacamelina", "quinoagrasscloverley", 
    "quinoaquinoa", "quinoaspringcereal", "springcerealcamelina", 
    "springcerealgrasscloverley", "springcerealquinoa", "springcerealspringcereal"
    ), class = "factor")), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Please also format inline code for readability, I helped you this time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can loop over column which has "Pair" in the dataframe check if the required pattern in present or not, create a matrix of logical vectors and select rows which have no occurrence of the pattern.

```
cols <- grep("Pair", names(df))
df[rowSums(sapply(df[cols],function(x) grepl("quinoaquinoa|lupinelupine", x)))== 0, ]
```

Comment: Thanks, it works! Would you mind explaining a bit how this one works?

Comment: @BellaLin  Using `grep` we first find out our columns which has "Pair" in it. Then we loop over those columns using `sapply` and check which of them have the required pattern in it. Just run `sapply(df[cols],function(x) grepl("quinoaquinoa|lupinelupine", x))` and you'll get a matrix with TRUE/FALSE value in it indicating whether the pattern is present in it or not. Now we do `rowSums` and select only those rows which has no occurrence of the pattern at all in their row. (`== 0`).

Answer (score 1):

There is no string containing "quinoaquinoa" or "lupinelupine" in your dataframe. I think the pattern you're using is inccorect. This works : `filter_at(df, vars(contains("Pair")), any_vars(str_detect(., pattern = "quinoa|lupine")))`